# Can Visual Studio 2008 provide any of the functionality that Query Analyzer and Enterprise Manager provide?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2000, query-analyzer

I'm currently using MSSQL Server 2000 and to design tables, create and alter stored procedures as well as manage users and permissions I'm using Query Analyzer and Enterprise Manager. I also spend an awful lot of time in Visual Studio 2008 and rather jump out to other applications I was wondering if Visual Studio could help me do at least some of the things that Query Analyzer and Enterprise Manager let me do. And if so, what specifically?

Mainly I'm looking to:

- Check the database schema
- Edit stored procedures (with Intellisense available)
- Change object permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Server Explorer in Visual Studio. Server Explorer allows you to create/modify/drop/whatever procedures, tables, views, etc, though I can't see any way to modify security settings (users, roles, etc) through the UI. I recommend SQL Management Studio before using the integrated Server Explorer.

I've also just noticed a feature in the context menu for a data connection in Server Explorer called "allow sql/clr debugging." Haven't tried that but sounds like it may allow breakpoints, etc in SQL code. How cool would that be?

**Edit:** It seems that the Server Explorer may only be available in Pro or better versions of Visual Studio - ie, not in Express editions. Yet another reason to get the full version.

Answer (score 2):

Can you install SQL Server Management Studio? This is far more useful than VS, I think.

I don't like the VS interface and it's not good for query plans, results and tuning. However, some folk I work with appear happy with VS but mostly the c# guys. The SQL heads use SQL tools.

Comment: "Can you install SQL Server Management Studio?" I don't know. Where can I get it?

Comment: @Jonathon: Full version with full SQL , or Express here http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b